# How to show element (not toggle) below navigation bar when clicking on list item? (React)

Tags: html, reactjs

I am attaching a picture below. You can see a navigation bar (overflow is already scroll) and a few list items. What I want to solve is: when I click on a list  item, each time, I want it to show a different paragraph and picture below. For example, when I click on the Updates list item, I want to see a paragraph and picture related to that. When I click on the History list item, I want to see a different paragraph and picture. And so on... How to implement this in React? Thank you! ps. sorry, to clarify, this is NOT a react native app, this is a website, built with react, mobile first approach. :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLWtc.png

Comment: This is not a react-native mobile app right?

Comment: sorry, to clarify, this is NOT a react native app, this is a website, built with react, mobile first approach. :)

Comment: you should use browser router> https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start
Or, the same can be simulated using state in the same component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where will you get the image and content from for each link? Storing the data in state and then adding an onClick handler to the link should do the trick.

In the handler, you fetch the required content and use `this.setState` to change the values stored in state.